# Opening facebook app request notification from android device

Tags: android, facebook, notifications, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I want to invite Facebook friends to try my app with Facebook 'apprequests' method.

It works ok. The friend gets the notification, but if he clicks at the notification from the android notification bar and not from Facebook, it opens Facebook app and just loading without doing any thing else.

If he clicks at the notification from Facebook it works as it suppose to.
Do you have any ideas what I have to do, to fix this problem?